# Loading data from JSON file in to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to access the data from my JSON file to be used **within** my controller for further manipulation using Angular. To start, here are the first couple entries of the file 'cards.json'

```
{ "TheGrandTournament": [
{
  "name": "Buccaneer",
  "cardSet": "The Grand Tournament",
  "type": "Minion",
  "rarity": "Common",
  "cost": 1,
  "attack": 2,
  "health": 1,
  "text": "Whenever you equip a weapon, give it +1 Attack.",
  "collectible": true,
  "playerClass": "Rogue",
  "img": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/AT_029.
},
{
  "name": "Competitive Spirit",
  "cardSet": "The Grand Tournament",
  "type": "Spell",
  "rarity": "Rare",
  "cost": 1,
  "text": "<b>Secret:</b> When your turn starts, give your minions +
  "collectible": true,
  "playerClass": "Paladin",
  "img": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/AT_073.
  "mechanics": [{"name": "Secret"}]
}, ...
]}
```

I have had success with accessing the information from my view using this code

```
<div ng-controller="CardCtrl">
    <button id="loadbtn" ng-click="load()">Load</button><br>
    <div ng-repeat="cards in data.TheGrandTournament | limitTo:2">
        <pre>{{ cards.name }}</pre>
    </div>
</div
```

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('cards', []).controller('CardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.method = 'GET';
        $scope.url = 'cards.json';

        $scope.load = function() {
            $scope.code = null;
            $scope.response = null;

            $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
                then(function(response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
                    console.log("Read file", $scope.url, "successfully.");
                }, function(response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
                    console.log("Error reading", $scope.url, ".");
                });
        };

        $scope.cardData = angular.fromJson($scope.data[0]);
        console.log($scope.cardData);

    }]);
```

The error returned when trying to output $scope.cardData to a console log is

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
```

I tried then parsing the data from the json object using angular.fromJson() but it is not working as I am intending.

Comment: You shouldn't refer to $scope.data as array with [0] in the bottom – try something like $scope.cardData = angular.fromJson($scope.data)[0]; instead

Comment: You get $scope.data within a promise, so when you try to assign it to $scope.cardData, it might not be available yet

Comment: Is it required to use a factory to import data from the JSON and then access is using the controller? (I have yet to try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `$scope.data` into the success callback of the promise:

```
$http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url}).
  then(function(response) {
    $scope.cardData = response.data.TheGrandTournament;
    console.log("Read file", $scope.url, "successfully.");
    console.log($scope.cardData);
  }, function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
    console.log("Error reading", $scope.url, ".");
  });
    // scope parameter data is not accessible here, as it's not yet added
    //$scope.cardData = angular.fromJson($scope.data[0]);
    //console.log($scope.cardData);

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, making progress now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:
$scope.data = response.data;

with:
$scope.data = response.data.TheGrandTournament;

Comment: That doesn't alleviate the fact that $scope.data is being returned as 'undefined' when I'm attempting to use it within the controller

Comment: Initialize $scope.cardData inside .then function.  You are working with promise here.

Comment: Okay, definitely getting somewhere. I can now see [the full JSON object](http://imgur.com/A3z99fM). I think I'll need to look in to handling the promise object, I haven't learned anything with this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
$scope.cardData = angular.fromJson($scope.data[0]);
```

with:

```
$scope.cardData = angular.fromJson($scope.data["TheGrandTournament"][0]);
```

Comment: Still comes back with TypeError: Cannot read property 'TheGrandTournament' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:82)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4478)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9136)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8248)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7680)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7684)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7684)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7555)
    at angular.js:1662
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15989)